# NotBlank does not work for embedded forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('evaluation', EvaluationType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
        ],
        'error_bubbling' => false,

    ]);
    $builder->add('qualification', QualificationType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank()
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Controller action:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(
    '', RatingCreateType::class, null, []
);

$form->submit(json_decode('{}', true));

if ($form->isValid()) {
        // todo
    } else {
        var_dump($form->getData()); exit;
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
    object(App\Form\DTO\RatingCreateDTO)#626 (2) {
  ["qualification"]=>
  object(App\Form\DTO\Rating\QualificationDTO)#1022 (2) {
    ["criteria"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["classification"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["evaluation"]=>
  object(App\Form\DTO\Rating\EvaluationDTO)#993 (2) {
    ["criteria"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["classification"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Symfony creates "qualification" and "evaluation" even though this parameters does not exists in submitted data. And the result is that NotBlank does not work cause this parameters seems to be set.

How can I configure the form fields to get not blank validation error when "qualification" and "evaluation" parameters does not exists in submitted data?

Comment: NotBlank only checks if the submitted data is not empty. It does not check if the values are not set at all. If you want to do that you need to mark these fields as `required`. You might also want to check if you need a check for `NotNull` as `NotBlank` only checks for a blank value, but not for null values